# Put a vote to close button in the 'on hold' box

Tags: feature-request

In the on hold as (off topic/duplicate/etc) box, should there be a link inside the box that opens the flagging box to the appropriate reason? This would speed up voting to close, and make it easier for people who want to close it,

Comment: You do realize that "on hold" questions are *already* closed? They are just displayed as "on hold" for a few days to encourage editing and reopening (when appropriate).

Comment: @animuson Oh. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, On Hold == Closed. It's simply a different wording so that new users don't think, "Oh no, my question got closed! I guess I'll just have to abandon it or repost it." On Hold questions become Closed after 7 days, but it really makes no difference, it's just the wording that changes.

Comment: @Cole Okay okay, I'll change it :P